# java FilenameFilter regex (look ahead)

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, filefilter

I am trying to filter files using FilenameFilter to grep files files in a directory.

```
% ls -1
DirFilter.class
DirList.class
DirList.java
doctors.txt
node.l
rels.l
```

I am trying to filter `node.l` and `rels.l`. Filter should succeed if and only if **both** files are present.

I tried my regex on debuggex.com and it seems to work as expected : 
http://www.debuggex.com/embed/CZgVeUE2iWsNfRNG

my regex  : `(?s)node.l.?(?=(rels.l))`

but when I run it through `DirList.java` filter it doesn't work..

```
% java DirList "(?s)node.l.?(?=(rels.l))"
<no-output>
```

Now I am using DirList.java from Thinking in Java
http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs476/tijava2/c10/DirList.java

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any regex method in `DirFilter` class from code in your link. `return f.indexOf(afn) != -1;` doesn't use regex.

Answer (score 1):

`DirList` is evaluating your regex against each file name separately, not as a single `\n` delimited directory listing string as returned by `ls`.  Your regex will never match under those conditions since it never sees more than one file name at a time.

Answer (score 1):

FilenameFilter works for single file not for groups of files so regex will be applied only to that single file. Instead of regex try maybe this way:

1. take name of file
2. - if it is `node.l` check if `new File(currentDir+"/rels.l").exists()`.
   - if it is `rels.l` check if `new File(currentDir+"/node.l").exists()`.